# Python Import class error, trying to understand the root directory __init__.py

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am just 4 days old to python. I am just trying to understand the root  __init__.py import functionality. Googled lot to understand the same but not able to find one useful link (may be my search key is not relevant) . Please share some links.

I am getting error as "ImportError: cannot import name Person"

Below is the structure

```
Example(directory)
    model
        __init__.py (empty)
        myclass.py
    __init__.py
    run.py
```

myclass.py

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "Raja"

    def print_name(self):
        print self.name
```

__init__.py

```
from model.myclass import Person
```

run.py

```
from model import Person

def donext():
    person = Person()
    person.print_name()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    donext()
```

Comment: `Person` isn't in `model` -- it's in `model.myclass`.  You're doing the import correctly in `__init__.py`.  Why did you do it differently in `run.py`?

Comment: Why have you added `flask` tag?

Comment: @john-gordon in run.py, I am just trying to import from \__init__.py and use the same

Comment: @gonczor Sorry, removed hence its not applicable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either, as @gonczor suggested, you can simply leave __init__ empty (moreover, you don't need the root one) and import directly from the package:

```
from model.myclass import Person
```

Or, if you intentionally want to flatten the interface of the package, this is as simple as this:

model/__init__.py

```
from myclass import Person
```

run.py

```
from model import Person
```

Answer (score 1):

The error basically says the interpreter can't find anything that would match `Person` in a given namespace, in your case `model` package. It's because it's in `model.myclass` package, but it's imported to `root` and not to `run`.

Modules in python are basically directories with `__init__.py` script. But it's tricky to import anything at root level from **init**. And moreover, it's not necessary.

OK, so this means solution is either to import directly from `model` package, or from the rott-level `__init__.py`. I would recommend the former method, since it's more commonly used. You can do it this way:

```
from model.myclass import Person

def donext():
    person = Person()
    person.print_name()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    donext()
```

And leave `__init__.py` empty. They are used only for initialization, so there is no need to import everything to them.

You could put something to your `model/__init__.py` and then import it in `myclass.py` like:

`__init__.py`:

```
something = 0
```

`myclass.py`:

```
from . import something
print something
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, learned to define in the sub directory level \__init__.py declaration and access from your code

Comment: Glad I could help :)